# How to make multiple bluetooth connections in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have been trying to connect multiple android phones to my app using bluetooth multiple connections concurrenlty.
Have followed the solution of a chatting app shared on android samples for bluetooth.
But I am able to only connect my phone to only one device(phone) at a time.

My code is exactly the same as that given in the sample demo on android devloper site.
any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the demo that you followed.

Comment: the code link is given below, but i am not able to made the code tweaks for having multiple connections for making it something like multi chatting app ..  https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: Thanks for reading .. after a deep research in to the existing code for single connections, and making some code tweaks , i am able to successfully connect multiple phones with Bluetooth. The key here is to have dedicated threads for each Socket connections as we can have only one connection per socket unlike http connection. And ofcourse, different UUID for every device.